# Check if for multiple values BUT one needs an extra line

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

My first question..!
Hi all, as a guy trying to learn programming/Python to be exact I have an issue that I would like to address. I have written some code that works as expected.

```
for i in range(81):
    if i in (30, 60, 80):
        if i == 80:
            ab += str(a) + '*' + str(b) + '<>'
        ab = ab.rstrip('<>')
        my_list += my_func(ab)
        ab = ''
    ab += str(a) + '*' + str(b) + '<>'
```

Yet I don't think this part is the pythonic way to go:

```
if i in (30, 60, 80):
    if i == 80:
```

There should be a way for me to say if i == 80 then do the standard 'if' conditions AFTER **this** extra code.

I hope I explained the issue properly. Thanks!

PS: This is an example code. I'm trying to find the proper logic only. Dont get stuck with the results.

Edit: I forgot to enter this line when posting my question (that's why some didn't understand the code):

```
my_list += my_func(ab)
```

Also For extra points  :)  I'd love it if there was a way that this line doesn't have to be written twice!

```
ab += str(a) + '*' + str(b) + '<>'
```

Comment: I think that's perfectly okay the way it it. You _could_ do `if i == 80: ... elif i in (30, 60): ...`, but that would duplicate the two `ab = ...` lines and be not as clear.

Comment: Speaking of which, that `ab = ''` will just undo any changes you do to `ab` before that. The entire code makes no sense. Why do you `+ '<>'` to `ab` only to `rstrip` it off again?

Comment: I missed a line there: there is a list that takes a function of ab.. editted

Comment: I also think this is perfectly fine, the only thing, use sets instead of tuple when comparing values. So, `if i in {30, 60, 80}`... And if some people tell you not to, refer to documentation which clearly recommends sets for membership testing [(docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

Comment: @scharette would set run faster than tuple in the if statement? Speed is very important for me.

Comment: @Mr.Robot I'm not sure if you will notice it (matter of ms/ns). But if speed is really crucial, try it. It is suppose to be faster yes.

Comment: If speed is your main concern, you should profile the code to see what is taking the most time.

Comment: @scharette Speed is very important. my program gives a result in about 4-6 seconds.. sometimes 3 but i need it to be under 2 (a similar code runs in 1 second written in C#. I haven't checked its code though. but the result is the same. I want to believe Python can be as fast. I will keep your suggestion in mind and might convert all similar statements with sets. Thank you!

 **ScottHunter
I am kind of new.. I have been reading on how to test my program since last night. I will do so once i figure the best (and simplest) way in Python3

Comment: @Mr.Robot Your welcome. let me know the timings please.

Comment: @scharette I found a way to profile my time using a module: line_profiler. The bottleneck seems to do nothing with my code but a single line:

**with urllib.request.urlopen(#xxx#) as request**..  I will keep the set option in mind for future coding. Thanks again!

Comment: @Mr.Robot thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do two statements in the for loop? 
Like :

```
for i in range(81):
    if i == 80:
        <your code>
    if i in [30, 60, 80]:
        <your code>
    <code for every i>
```

Comment: Because there's code that's needed for _both_ cases?

Comment: sorry i editted my code. there is an extra line now. the code: ab += str(a) + '*' + str(b) + '<>' needs to be executed before the final iteration.

Comment: @tobias_k, ok I haven't see the extra 80 in the tuple. But I think there is no better way to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the `if i == 80:...` bit *above* the other `if` to avoid any nesting or duplication, but not sure if that's is what makes you think this isn't Pythonic enough:

```
for i in range(81):
    if i == 80:
        ab += str(a) + '*' + str(b) + '<>'
    if i in (30, 60, 80):
        ab = ab.rstrip('<>')
        my_list += my_func(ab)
        ab = ''
    ab += str(a) + '*' + str(b) + '<>'
```

Comment: Just my 2 cents, but I like OP's original version better. There it is clear that the `i == 80` is meant as a special case of `i in (30, 60, 80)` whereas here one might think that those conditions should be exclusive (even if there's no `elif`).

Comment: My program is taking longer than expected. about 4-6 seconds to get the result i want. That's why i am scrolling through my code to see what can be done better. This question was a result of that. Thank you for your answer but it isn't what I am looking for. I think there should be a way to make this look more professional and faster.

Comment: @ScottHunter in the FOR loop I have an IF that checks values, one being the last iteration of the FOR. But in order to get the correct result, I have to add the extra line within the **nested** IF that checks for the same value as its parent. I stated I'm new to programming. I'm trying to learn the best way to code and spent endless hours in doing so. I do not know if this is the proper way to achieve my goal. But I believe there could be a better way of doing it.

Comment: If you believe there is something *better*, you must see some deficiency in what you wrote; you have yet to explain what that is. It works, it is clear; until you identify where it is wasting time, you have no basis for complaining about its speed.

Comment: @ScottHunter and as a side note, you did present an alternative way.. but it would probably be less efficient. Because the **unnested** IF would be checked **80** times while the **nested** IF would be checked only **3** times (as far as I can tell that is). That is one reason I did not accept your answer. FYI

Comment: Your original post said nothing about efficiency, and you *still* haven't explained what it is about your code that is deficient.  At this point, I'd be offended if you accepted my answer.

Comment: @ScottHunter this code works, it gives me my result. But I thought it wasn't professional (or Pythonic) due to the fact I have to repeat the check value of 80 twice in order to achieve my goal. That's why I posted my question.

Comment: Moving the `if i == 80:` up just requires the condition be checked _every_ iteration of the outer `for i in range(81):` instead of only three times where it was originally. This can only be slower and is certainly not "pythonic".